# React router and rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router

after setup a simple react with rails with users i would like to get the user show page.

but after read the react router doc i still not get how to pass the id or any params to the link.

```
 api_user GET    /api/users/:access_token(.:format)       api/users#show
```

so i did

```
 <Route path="/api/users/:access_token" component={User} />
```

and

```
 <Link  to="/users"}>User show</Link>
```

and show nothing.

please someone can spare a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to pass a parameter to your component via the URL. Here `access_token` is the parameter:

```
<Route path="/users/:access_token" component={User} />
```

When using `Link` you will need to add the actual token in the `to` path. Here is one way you can do it:

```
const token = 'foobarbaz';
const path = '/users/' + token;

<Link to={path}>User show</Link>
```

In your `User` component you can then access the value in the URL through props `this.props.match.params['access_token']` and use it to call your api.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const token = this.props.match.params['access_token'];
    const apiURL = "/api/users/" + token;
    // call api
}
```